# TokenMismatchException error in laravel api

Tags: php, laravel

My code is as shown below:

web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('/xyz','xyz@store');
```

xyz.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class xyz extends Controller
{
     /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $name = $request->name;
        $email = $request->email;
        $password = $request->password;
        return response()
            ->json(['name' => $name, 'email' => $email,'password' =>$password]);
    }
}
```

as soon as I run this api it gives me the following error:[image]

Here , I am not even using the form, otherwise I could have insert csrf_token. Is there anything missing from this API?

Comment: Move your route to `api.php` and access with with the `api` prefix. The web routes use `web` middleware group, which needs a valid csrf token to be passed with every form request. Unless you're creating this route to be used with ajax for your frontend, you won't need csrf check.

Comment: @Sandeesh Should I put **api** prefix in the url or somewhere else?

Comment: Any route defined in the `api.php` file will be prefixed with `api` by default. So your route would become `http://localhost:8000/api/xyz`

Comment: @Sandeesh can't I remove that **api** somehow?

Comment: Ok here's the alternative. Keep the route in `web.php` and add the route to the csrf exception list. In the file `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`, add your route to the `$except` property. Which would look like `protected $except = ['/post'];`

Comment: Keep in mind that if you're working with frontend and this route is used in an ajax call, you shouldn't disable csrf. This leads to security risk. In that case you need to pass the csrf token along with your ajax request. Only when you're consuming the route as a pure api, you wouldn't need csrf validation.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using ajax request you must add :

```
headers : {
           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          },
```

Follow these steps :

Store the token in a "meta" tag at the top of your root view file (layouts/app.blade.php)...

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Make sure to download Postman Interceptor (to sync Postman with the browser?) and turn it "on" in both the browser and Postman.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?hl=en

Do something in your app in the browser, open up the console and search in the head for the value of the csrf_token...

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="cbpj1L7ym6fdPJhl5Fc0mH4MMU71gK1zatutgC3d">
```

Add a header within Postman...

```
X-CSRF-TOKEN        cbpj1L7ym6fdPJhl5Fc0mH4MMU71gK1zatutgC3d
```

Comment: I added <meta name="csrf-token"> with content in my app.blade.php and put header content just like you said, but still it is giving the same error